# grep to extract substrings in a string

Tags: shell-script, grep

I have an output for a command as below.

```
Heading1
   I am one value.
   I am another value.
   I am third value. 
Heading2
   I am some value.
   I am someother value. 
   I am new value. 
Heading3
```

As we can see, there is a space in the beginning of the line if it is not a **heading**. I am trying to extract all the values under Heading1. I need the output as,

```
I am one value.
I am another value.
I am third value.
```

If I try the command,

```
grep mycommand | heading1
```

It gives me only the Heading1 line.

**UPDATE:**

I know, I have to extract the string from the starting of `Heading1`. But, I do not know the ending string (i.e, here I have mentioned as Heading2, but I won't be knowing it).

All I know is, I have to extract everything till the next heading which starts in a new line.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly how to do it:

```
$ sed -n -e '/Heading1/,/Heading2/ p' file.txt | grep "^ " | sed 's/^[ ]\+//g'
I am one value.
I am another value.
I am third value.
```

A bit more condensed version, makes use of `pcregrep` which allows for multiline matching:

```
$ pcregrep -M 'Heading1(\n|.)*Heading2' file.txt | grep "^[ ]\+"
   I am one value.
   I am another value.
   I am third value.
```

To get rid of the spaces at the begining using this method, you could make use of `grep`'s PCRE facility:

```
$  pcregrep -M 'Heading1(\n|.)*Heading2' a.txt | grep -oP "^[ ]{3}\K.*"
I am one value.
I am another value.
I am third value.
```

Finally here's a `sed` and `awk` solution.

```
$ sed -n -e '/Heading1/,/Heading2/ p' file.txt | awk '/^ / {sub(/^[ ]+/, ""); print}'
I am one value.
I am another value.
I am third value.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I do not know the second string's name as Heading2? It can be anything and all I know is, a heading starts in that line.\

Comment: @Ramesh - do you know anything about it or not?

Comment: No, I do not know anything about the second string. All I know is the first string.

Comment: I will update my question with a proper example.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
yourcommand | grep -A3 Heading1 | grep -v Heading1
```

Comment: Explaining *why* that should work would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

Here is awk solution:

```
yourcommand | awk '/Heading1/ {for(n=0; n<3; n++) {getline; $1=$1; print}}'
```

**Update**

If between `Heading1` and the end string only have lines start with space, you can do like this:

```
yourcommand | awk '/Heading1/ {flag=1;next} /^\w+/ {flag=0} {$1=$1} flag'
```